# Routing Remote Actors: Peer not authenticated

Tags: scala, networking, deployment, routes, akka

I am I am trying to route remote actors following this example:

http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/snapshot/scala/routing.html#Remotely_Deploying_Routees

Here is the code:

```
val system = ActorSystem("RemoteSystem", ConfigFactory.load.getConfig("remotecreation"))

val addresses = Seq(AddressFromURIString("akka://ActorApplication@172.17.100.224:2552"),
            AddressFromURIString("akka://ActorApplication@172.17.100.232:2552"))


val worker = system.actorOf(Props[authNetActor.AuthNetActorMain].withRouter(RemoteRouterConfig(RoundRobinRouter(5), addresses)))
```

However I am getting an error saying that one of the server ip addresses is not authenticated.

Here is the error (this is from: 172.17.100.224:2552):

```
[ERROR] [09/20/2012 18:13:02.192] [ActorApplication-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-11 [akka://ActorApplication/remote/RemoteSystem@172.17.100.231:2554/user/$a/c1] peer not authenticated
javax.net.ssl.SSLPeerUnverifiedException: peer not authenticated
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSessionImpl.getPeerCertificates(SSLSessionImpl.java:371)
    at org.apache.http.conn.ssl.AbstractVerifier.verify(AbstractVerifier.java:128)
    at org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLSocketFactory.connectSocket(SSLSocketFactory.java:390)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator.openConnection(DefaultClientConnectionOperator.java:148)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPoolEntry.open(AbstractPoolEntry.java:149)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPooledConnAdapter.open(AbstractPooledConnAdapter.java:121)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.tryConnect(DefaultRequestDirector.java:562)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:415)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:820)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:776)
    at dispatch.BlockingHttp$class.dispatch$BlockingHttp$$execute(Http.scala:45)
    at dispatch.BlockingHttp$$anonfun$execute$1$$anonfun$apply$3.apply(Http.scala:58)
    at dispatch.BlockingHttp$$anonfun$execute$1$$anonfun$apply$3.apply(Http.scala:58)
    at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:108)
    at dispatch.BlockingHttp$$anonfun$execute$1.apply(Http.scala:58)
at dispatch.Http.pack(Http.scala:25)
    at dispatch.BlockingHttp$class.execute(Http.scala:53)
    at dispatch.Http.execute(Http.scala:21)
    at dispatch.HttpExecutor$class.x(executor.scala:36)
    at dispatch.Http.x(Http.scala:21)
    at dispatch.HttpExecutor$class.when(executor.scala:50)
    at dispatch.Http.when(Http.scala:21)
    at dispatch.HttpExecutor$class.apply(executor.scala:60)
    at dispatch.Http.apply(Http.scala:21)
    at models.AuthorizeNet$.AuthorizeNetDPM(main.scala:187)
    at authNetActor.AuthNetActorMain$$anonfun$receive$1.apply(AuthNetActor.scala:68)
    at authNetActor.AuthNetActorMain$$anonfun$receive$1.apply(AuthNetActor.scala:12)
    at akka.actor.Actor$class.apply(Actor.scala:318)
    at authNetActor.AuthNetActorMain.apply(AuthNetActor.scala:9)
    at akka.actor.ActorCell.invoke(ActorCell.scala:626)
    at akka.dispatch.Mailbox.processMailbox(Mailbox.scala:197)
    at akka.dispatch.Mailbox.run(Mailbox.scala:179)
    at akka.dispatch.ForkJoinExecutorConfigurator$MailboxExecutionTask.exec(AbstractDispatcher.scala:516)
    at akka.jsr166y.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:259)
    at akka.jsr166y.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.runTask(ForkJoinPool.java:975)
    at akka.jsr166y.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1479)
    at akka.jsr166y.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:104)
```

The error occurs only for this server and the difference between them are that the code path is different and they create actor systems on their own local ip addresses. Otherwise the code for these two actor systems are the same.

I'm not sure exactly how to fix this error or why it is thrown for just one server.

Any help is appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems an SSL handshaking exception.

Maybe the involved server have not a valid SSL certificate, or you have not registered the untrusted certificate in the client keystore.

Comment: What turned out to be the issue was that the cacerts file in the failing server was not as up to date as the other one. We ended up just copying it over and now it works.